# Do I need to enhance my performance in CrossFit by extra working out with fitness equipment and machines?

Tags: weightlifting, training, crossfit

I've just start going to CrossFit training, my background is gymnastic and snowboarding plus I run three times per week about (30 km/19 miles). I'm 27 years old.

I do really good when it comes to cardio exercises, but I do terrible in weightlifting. I have no experience in weightlifting at all. Yesterday I couldn't do a single power snatch. I mean I couldn't even lift the 20 kg barbell above my waist with no extra weight on it (which btw was very embarrassing).

Should I ask my coach to give me some feedback on my technique or should I just repeat the exercise until I can do it.

I thought instead of working with body weight exclusively, I could also use some gym equipment help me to build strength but I'm not sure if this is going to help me or harm me.

I'm not quite sure if I can ask my question here, if it's off-topic then a single comment is more than enough to make me remove the question.

Comment: for a beginner I wouldn't recommend crossfit at all. I would recommend a starting strength conditioning program for your weight lifting. Crossfit can be great in some respects once you know the movements but often it can be used in a way which over emphasizes number of reps over form which can be dangerous. A starting strength program will teach you the movements for the most important lifts squat, bench, deadlift, press, and power clean to start. Just my two cents. Best of success with your training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I do terrible in weightlifting. I have no experience in weightlifting at all.

This is the reason you 'struggle', weightlifting is very much a specific 'skill'. It takes years of practise. If you were to take one of your CrossFit class members snowboarding for the first time I imagine they'd feel pretty terrible next to you. Cardio and weightlifting build up the muscles differently. So being strong and having good cardio is a completely different type of muscle. As others have advised, I would get some coaching.

Just as a side note the snatch is a difficult movement. It's very technical (in comparison to something like a squat) and requires a good deal of co-ordination.

Whether you can do the bar or not any good weightlifting coach wouldn't let a beginner progress much past the bar until they had the movement down to a reasonable standard.

I would wager most people start with the bar, whether they are strong or not because of the technical nature of the snatch. For example, I bet you could press the bar overhead without too much issue and I'd also bet that you can squat the bar without too much issue. So it's not really that you're weak, it's more that you don't know how to do the movement and you haven't practiced enough to gain the muscle memory. Also after having been around weightlifters I'd say that 99% of coaches prefer a weak beginner to someone that's already strong because a weak lifter has to focus on technique more and it's easier to build strength than good technique.

If you wanted some more information there's plenty of good weightlifting channels on YouTube. I would recommend Zack Telander, Max Aita (juggernaut strength) for informative content that doesn't really require any prior weightlifting knowledge. There are some good videos out there that feature Dmitry Klokov, Oleksiy Torokhtiy or Gabriel Sincraian who are all Olympians. However the latter 3 might require some basic knowledge of some weightlifting jargon.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I ask my couch to give me some feedback on my technique

Yes. Absolutely. This is the prime time to start asking professionals for help. That's why the coach there. If you're paying for the class then it's to your benefit to get as much help as possible.

The coach may tell you whether or not you should do extra work outside the class. You may simply need to continue practicing. You may have to do something else that will help you build up to the main workout. The coach would (hopefully) be skilled enough of a teacher to tell you what you need to do to progress.

> which btw was very embarrassing

Everyone starts somewhere. Almost every person beside you in that class was in the exact same position. I'd also make a wager that none of them could stand on a snowboard now if you were all taking snowboarding classes.